# Programmatically create a node with a menu link

Tags: nodes, 8

I created a node programmatically with the following code.

```
$data = array(
  'type' => 'inception_article',
  'title' => $msg->name,
  'body' => array(
    'value' => $msg->body,
    'format' => 'full_html'
  )
);

$node = Node::create($data);
$node->save();
```

I would now also like to create the menu link for the node, but I cannot figure out how to do that in Drupal 8.

How can I programmatically create a menu link for a node I create?

Answer (score 1):

You can save menu link Separately using the below code on node save.

```
 $menu_link = MenuLinkContent::create(array(
      'title' => 'Menu Title', // Menu title is your title of menu, in this case node title
      'path' => '/path/to/node', // Menu link something like '/node/'.$nid, replace $nid with your node id
      'menu_name' => 'navigation',
      'weight' => 0,
      'bundle' => 'menu_link_content',
 ));

 $menu_link->save();
```

Comment: Yes Its creating the menu link, and working fine. But while editing the node its not present under  "Menu Settings". How can i Do this ?

Answer (score 1):

To have the menu also on the node entity, you need to pass the link uri as entity:

```
MenuLinkContent::create([
  'title' => 'Menu title', // Menu title is your title of menu, in this case node title
  'link' => ['uri' => 'entity:node/' . $node->id()],
  'menu_name' => 'main',
  'weight' => 0,
])->save();
```